# Reading multiple messages using pipe in C?

Tags: c, file, process, fork, pipe

I understand that I can send a message from parent and receive it using read() from child using pipes, but what if I want to send multiple messages of different types (int, array..) to the child process? Is it possible to let the child process read them separately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define various `data types` in `enum` and then append this `enum` in the beginning of your `message`.

```
typedef enum 
{
INT,
CHAR,
FLOAT,
LONG
//other data types
} data_type_t;
```

Say, your message is:

```
stackoverflow
```

and you need to indicate to the reciever to read it as a string, so you can append it like:

```
1stackoverflow //here 1 indicates CHAR
```

So, that one the child reads it, it can extract the 1st character to see that it has to be interpreted as string (CHAR). Use it as:

```
#define READ 0 /* Read end of pipe */
#define WRITE 1 /* Write end of pipe */
. . .

int fd[2];
char *message = "some random message";
char modified_message[40];

data_type_t type = CHAR; // Say for this message you define the data type as char

sprintf(modified_message, "%d%s", type,  message);
write(fd[WRITE], message, strlen(message)+1);
. . .
```

The receiving end will extract the 1st bit of the `message` and knowing the `1st` bit you'll be able to interpret the type of the data contained.

Comment: thanks, what if the size of the message is unknown and might be over one bit?

Comment: There has to be some upper limit to the size of the message that can be sent, and if it's under that limit and terminated by a null, strlen will calculate it.